# How do I style an object property in Javascript? I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontWeight' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, object

So here's my code, and what I am trying to do is access "nom" property of an object, and styling it bold. Everything works, except for styling the object property, which gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontWeight' of undefined", even though the object and its property exist.

```js
var productes = [
    mobil = {
        nom: "Galaxy A51",
        preu: "300",
        img: "../media/mobil.jpg"
    },

    portatil = {
        nom: "Portatil Gaming",
        preu: "600",
        img: "../media/laptop.jpg"
    },
    
    pc = {
        nom: "PC Gaming Ultra",
        preu: "600",
        img: "../media/pc.jpg"
    },

    cpu = {
        nom: "CPU TURBO-X",
        preu: "200",
        img: "../media/cpu.jpg"
    },

    cadira = {
        nom: "Cadira Gaming Xtreme",
        preu: "399",
        img: "../media/chair.jpg"
    },

    ratoli = {
        nom: "Ratoli Gaming",
        preu: "99",
        img: "../media/mouse.jpg"
    },

    bitcoin = {
        nom: "Bitcoin",
        preu: "40 000",
        img: "../media/bitcoin.jpg"
    },

    monitor = {
        nom: "Pantalla Gaming 1Hz",
        preu: "400",
        img: "../media/monitor.jpg"
    },

    web = {
        nom: "Aquest lloc web",
        preu: "1 000 000",
        img: "../media/web.jpg"
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < productes.length; i++) {     //despres aixo anira atraves del array
                                                    //i les ficara totes en divs a la pagina
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var objNom = productes[i].nom;
    var objPreu = productes[i].preu + "&euro;";
    var image = document.createElement("img");

    //alguns estils i tal
    image.src = productes[i].img;
    div.style.cssText = "background-color: purple; width: 33%; padding: 10px; margin-top: 30px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 5px black;"
    image.style.cssText = "width: 100%;";
    div.innerHTML = objNom + "<br><br>" + "Preu: " + objPreu;
    objNom.style.fontWeight = "bold"; //REMOVE THIS LINE TO SEE THE CODE WORK

    //afegint el div al body i el imatge al div
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(image);
};
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Very sorry for some of the comments in the code being in Catalan, but they're not related to the question so please ignore them.

Comment: `objNom = productes[i].nom` is a _String_, not a DOM element, so `objNom.style` is undefined  — you might want to set `div.style.fontWeight = "bold"`

Answer (score -1):

Let me modernize your code while trying to solve your problem.

```
Object.values(productes).forEach(producte => {
  const {nom, preu, img} = producte
  let element = `
    <div class="producte">
      <span><strong>${nom}</strong>: ${preu} &euro;</span>
      <img src="${img}" />
    </div>`;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element);
})

// If you need "mobile", "monitor", "web" etc, replace the first line of script with the code down below, and remove ")" at the end.
// for (const [key, producte] of Object.entries(productes)) {
```

```
.producte {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 5px black;
}

.producte img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I didn't pay attention to your HTML outcome, but if you read my answer, you can see how it can be produced an HTML string.